# posicionar div en el centro(Reactjs +Tailwind)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind

```
            <IconContext.Provider value={{ size:'2rem'}}>
            <div className='p-2 mt-0 fixed w-full z-10 top-0 inline-flex'>
                <Link to={{ pathname: "../public/index.html" }}>
                <img src={Logo} alt='Logo' className='w-40 h-30 absolute cursor-pointer'/>
                </Link>
                <div className='cursor-pointer inline-flex gap-12 absolute top-8 left-56'>
                    <BsFillChatDotsFill className='hover:text-green-700'/>
                    <BsFillPersonFill className='hover:text-green-700'/>
                    <div>
                    <TiShoppingCart onClick ={()=> setModalPrice (!ModalPrice)} className='hover:text-green-700'/>
                    {ModalPrice ? (
                        <div className='bg-gray-400 w-64 h-32 rounded-2xl absolute top-14 left-0 z-10 opacity-60'>

                        </div>
                    ): null }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </IconContext.Provider>
        </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que intento hacer es que el logo junto a los iconos que ven en la imagen quiero que a medida la pantalla vaya teniendo mas width se vaya posicionando siempre en el centro

un ejemplo del caso a emular
https://i.imgur.com/VZ1D3hn.mp4

Comment: Si el logo debe ir al centro inevitablemente moverá a los otros 3 elementos ¿qué debe pasarles entonces, a dónde se deben mover?

Comment: el logo se mueve . pero en cuanto a los iconos no sucede ningún cambio

Comment: No termina de quedar claro entonces lo que buscas, por ejemplo ¿cuánto se debe mover y en que medida se debe mover?, ¿cómo se en qué medida debe alcanzar el centro el logo?

Comment: subi un ejemplo del caso. como puedes ver en el video el botón order now siempre se mantiene en el centro a medida que lo vayas alargando